# Authentication has been denied for this request

Tags: c#, android, entity-framework, authentication, identityserver4

I have created this identity server 4 project which works locally on my machine and also works when I deploy it to an internal server (production) in my company. Now I am facing an issue which is really confusing me when I move the deployed app from our internal server to a live (external) server
[image]
This error comes when i try getting data from the api because I am able to log in successfully and I even get the token. And when i check the idp log file, i get the following:

> [04:36:03 Information]  Starting host...
>
> [04:36:04 Information] IdentityServer4.Startup Starting
> IdentityServer4 version 4.0.2+58e6bc8a94236b81d1d3c606c8295203c7c1c9e2
>
> [04:36:04 Information] IdentityServer4.Startup Using the default
> authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Using Identity.Application as
> default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Using Identity.External as
> default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Using Identity.External as
> default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Using Identity.Application as
> default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Using Identity.Application as
> default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
>
> [04:36:04 Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime Now listening on:
> http://127.0.0.1:39619
>
> [04:36:04 Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime Application started.
> Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
>
> [04:36:04 Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime Hosting environment:
> Production
>
> [04:36:04 Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime Content root path:
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TaxRevenueIdp
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Login Url: /Account/Login
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Login Return Url Parameter:
> ReturnUrl
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Logout Url: /Account/Logout
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup ConsentUrl Url: /consent
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Consent Return Url Parameter:
> returnUrl
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Error Url: /home/error
>
> [04:36:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup Error Id Parameter: errorId
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Request path
> /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Endpoint
> enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler:
> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
>
> [04:36:05 Information]
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware Invoking
> IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
> for /connect/authorize
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint Start
> authorize request
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint User in
> authorize request: 00b6146c-0770-4c20-a29b-8427c37d4c99
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
> Start authorize request protocol validation
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
> TaxAdminCode found in database: True
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore client
> configuration validation for client TaxAdminCode succeeded.
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
> Checking for PKCE parameters
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
> No PKCE used.
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["profile", "openid", "email"] identity scopes in database
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["collectorapi"] API resources in database
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["collectorapi"] scopes in database
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
> Calling into custom validator:
> IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
> ValidatedAuthorizeRequest {"ClientId": "TaxAdminCode", "ClientName":
> "Tax Admin Code", "RedirectUri":
> "https://<>/PersolTaxService",
> "AllowedRedirectUris":
> ["https://.../PersolTaxService/signin-oidc"],
> "SubjectId": "00b6146c-0770-4c20-a29b-8427c37d4c99", "ResponseType":
> "code", "ResponseMode": "query", "GrantType": "authorization_code",
> "RequestedScopes": "collectorapi profile openid email", "State": null,
> "UiLocales": null, "Nonce": null,
> "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "DisplayMode": null,
> "PromptMode": "", "MaxAge": null, "LoginHint": null, "SessionId":
> "04847BC7FEBA51BF79477CAB9931AC35", "Raw": {"response_type": "code",
> "state": "", "client_id": "TaxAdminCode", "scope": "collectorapi
> profile openid email", "redirect_uri":
> "https://.../PersolTaxService"}, "$type":
> "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}
>
> [04:36:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultConsentService Client
> is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
>
> [04:36:05 Debug]
> IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator Creating
> Authorization Code Flow response.
>
> [04:36:05 Debug]
> IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore
> 2czi9SJKgRsF3kn39k7qgm9rgolATlMmAhlI464hJIs= not found in database
>
> [04:36:06 Information] IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService
> {"ClientId": "TaxAdminCode", "ClientName": "Tax Admin Code",
> "RedirectUri": "https://.../PersolTaxService",
> "Endpoint": "Authorize", "SubjectId":
> "00b6146c-0770-4c20-a29b-8427c37d4c99", "Scopes": "collectorapi
> profile openid email", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "Tokens":
> [{"TokenType": "code", "TokenValue": "****70F2", "$type": "Token"}],
> "Category": "Token", "Name": "Token Issued Success", "EventType":
> "Success", "Id": 2000, "Message": null, "ActivityId":
> "0HM2JM2P8F6QO:00000001", "TimeStamp": "2020-09-08T04:36:06.0000000Z",
> "ProcessId": 15124, "LocalIpAddress": "127.0.0.1:39619",
> "RemoteIpAddress": "154.160.19.136", "$type":
> "TokenIssuedSuccessEvent"}
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint Authorize
> endpoint response {"SubjectId":
> "00b6146c-0770-4c20-a29b-8427c37d4c99", "ClientId": "TaxAdminCode",
> "RedirectUri": "https://.../PersolTaxService",
> "State": null, "Scope": "collectorapi profile openid email", "Error":
> null, "ErrorDescription": null, "$type": "AuthorizeResponseLog"}
>
> [04:36:06 Debug]
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService Augmenting
> SignInContext
>
> [04:36:06 Information]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
> AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Request path
> /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Endpoint
> enabled: Token, successfully created handler:
> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
>
> [04:36:06 Information]
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware Invoking
> IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for
> /connect/token
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint Start token
> request.
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
> Start client validation
>
> [04:36:06 Debug]
> IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser Start
> parsing Basic Authentication secret
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ISecretsListParser Parser
> found secret: BasicAuthenticationSecretParser
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ISecretsListParser Secret
> id found: TaxAdminCode
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
> TaxAdminCode found in database: True
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore client
> configuration validation for client TaxAdminCode succeeded.
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
> Public Client - skipping secret validation success
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
> Client validation success
>
> [04:36:06 Information] IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService
> {"ClientId": "TaxAdminCode", "AuthenticationMethod": "SharedSecret",
> "Category": "Authentication", "Name": "Client Authentication Success",
> "EventType": "Success", "Id": 1010, "Message": null, "ActivityId":
> "0HM2JM2P8F6QO:00000002", "TimeStamp": "2020-09-08T04:36:06.0000000Z",
> "ProcessId": 15124, "LocalIpAddress": "127.0.0.1:39619",
> "RemoteIpAddress": "154.160.19.136", "$type":
> "ClientAuthenticationSuccessEvent"}
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
> Start token request validation
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
> Start validation of authorization code token request
>
> [04:36:06 Debug]
> IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore
> 2czi9SJKgRsF3kn39k7qgm9rgolATlMmAhlI464hJIs= found in database: True
>
> [04:36:06 Debug]
> IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore removing
> 2czi9SJKgRsF3kn39k7qgm9rgolATlMmAhlI464hJIs= persisted grant from
> database
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
> Validation of authorization code token request success
>
> [04:36:06 Information]
> IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator Token request
> validation success, {"ClientId": "TaxAdminCode", "ClientName": "Tax
> Admin Code", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "Scopes": null,
> "AuthorizationCode":
> "06E8389B3304937E176059F68E9DDA389FAC86D0C1C0D97C9851D96F29E270F2",
> "RefreshToken": null, "UserName": null,
> "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "Tenant": null, "IdP":
> null, "Raw": {"grant_type": "authorization_code", "code":
> "06E8389B3304937E176059F68E9DDA389FAC86D0C1C0D97C9851D96F29E270F2",
> "redirect_uri":
> "https://.../PersolTaxService", "client_id":
> "TaxAdminCode"}, "$type": "TokenRequestValidationLog"}
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
> TaxAdminCode found in database: True
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore client
> configuration validation for client TaxAdminCode succeeded.
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["profile", "openid", "email"] identity scopes in database
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["collectorapi"] API resources in database
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["collectorapi"] scopes in database
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService Getting
> claims for access token for client: TaxAdminCode
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService Getting
> claims for access token for subject:
> 00b6146c-0770-4c20-a29b-8427c37d4c99
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService Claim
> types from profile service that were filtered: ["sub", "amr", "idp",
> "auth_time"]
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
> TaxAdminCode found in database: True
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore client
> configuration validation for client TaxAdminCode succeeded.
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["profile", "openid", "email"] identity scopes in database
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["collectorapi"] API resources in database
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
> Found ["collectorapi"] scopes in database
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService Getting
> claims for identity token for subject:
> 00b6146c-0770-4c20-a29b-8427c37d4c99 and client: TaxAdminCode
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService Claim
> types from profile service that were filtered: ["sub", "amr", "idp",
> "auth_time"]
>
> **[04:36:06 Information] IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService
> {"ClientId": "TaxAdminCode", "ClientName": "Tax Admin Code",
> "RedirectUri": null,** "Endpoint": "Token", "SubjectId":
> "00b6146c-0770-4c20-a29b-8427c37d4c99", "Scopes": "collectorapi
> profile openid email", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "Tokens":
> [{"TokenType": "id_token", "TokenValue": "****Mj6A", "$type":
> "Token"}, {"TokenType": "access_token", "TokenValue": "****zTOg",
> "$type": "Token"}], "Category": "Token", "Name": "Token Issued
> Success", "EventType": "Success", "Id": 2000, "Message": null,
> "ActivityId": "0HM2JM2P8F6QO:00000002", "TimeStamp":
> "2020-09-08T04:36:06.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 15124, "LocalIpAddress":
> "127.0.0.1:39619", "RemoteIpAddress": "154.160.19.136", "$type":
> "TokenIssuedSuccessEvent"}
>
> [04:36:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint Token request
> success.

And I suspect the RedirectUri which null at this level IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService.
I am really lost on how to solve this and also the log file in the api app doesn't load load anything.
So any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being late and for not reading well what I posted some months ago.
This issue had solved and it was the scopes I provided that were wrong. I manually entered them in production instead of moving the complete idp database from development to production server and configure the new links in production.
Thanks